# Where is the conventions help page?

Tags: support, new-users

I happened across a(nother) question where the author isn't aware of some of the conventions on SO, such as not putting tags in the title and not saying Hi! or TIA.

It would be nice to be able to point the OP to a short list of such conventions, but I can't find it.

Please would someone let me know where the *concise list of things new posters need to know* is.

- It is not [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
- The [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) makes no mention of these things.
- [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) is no help for this.
- [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) says, yes, scroll down further, a bit more, well I'm not entirely sure, does it say I should make the title into a question?

Comment: On Meta.se, there is the [`etiquette` tag which has a number of these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etiquette), including the favorite [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Neither of those resources are concise. While we may *hope* that a new poster would conscientiously read through all of that prior to their first post, it is not a realistic expectation.

Comment: You can't really slap a user with such a link.  It is, you know, not [welcoming].  Users learn this by seeing other users edit their post.  If you want to do this anyway, and existing meta [faq] is not concise enough, then consider to just create your own.

Comment: ... and pointing them to that much information just to explain your edits to their post won't help them.

Comment: @HansPassant I was thinking of being able to edit a new user's post and then leave a comment mentioning that I had done so with a link to the most-prevalent conventions. I imagine it not being very welcoming to spend minutes creating a first question and then someone comes along and half re-writes it.

Comment: My default take on this is to leave clear edit summaries -- no need for lengthy explanations in them; the main goal is making it clear the edit wasn't arbitrary. It's anybody's guess, of course, how often those summaries are read.

Comment: How about the [tour] and the [behavior](/help/behavior) page?

Comment: @ale The tour page makes no mention of these things. I expect that there is almost no chance that a new user would have read the behavior, or even the "Our model" pages (SO may have stats to prove or disprove that idea), and they don't address these small things that many new users do. [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) doesn't mention removing greetings or thanks.

Comment: If you are *half-rewriting* a question, it should have just been closed most likely.

Comment: @feelingunwelcome If the fluff wasn't there, it would be less than half-rewriting, and so hopefully chronic dismay on the part of editors would be reduced.

Answer (score 5):

May I suggest:

---

There are some conventions on Stack Overflow that you need to know about when posting a question. Here is a brief summary of some of them, followed by short explanations of the reasons behind them:

- Avoid using the question's tags in the title if you can.
- Don't add "Hello" or "Thanks!"
- Stick around for a while after you've asked the question to answer comments.
- Wait a little while after an answer appears before accepting it.

There's no *need* to have the tags in the title because they appear next to the question already.

We like questions on Stack Overflow to contain only the information needed, so we forego greetings and such. Please don't worry if your question gets edited and someone removes things like that - it's normal here.

Sometimes a question doesn't have all the information we need to answer it, in which case people will add comments asking for more details or clarification. A newly-asked question gets featured on the home page, so if those comments aren't answered quickly then your question might get down-voted and closed before you even see it again. Responding to those comments quickly can save your question.

The first answer to appear may solve your problem, in which case it deserves an up-vote. But remember that Stack Overflow is used by programmers all around the world, so it could be that a better answer comes along later and you would prefer to accept that instead.

---

Is there anything else they need to know at first, bearing in mind I'm hoping it will be a minimal list of short items?

Comment: Try to answer __each__ question posted in the comments. Always __Tag__ for the target platform. Always call things by their __right__ name, eg: DataGridView != GridView != DataGrid. Always __google__ before asking. Always tell us if and what the __debugger__ did to help..

Comment: @TaW - that is pretty idealistic but unrealistic expectations for the amount of effort anyone is going to put into a first question, even first 100 questions.

Comment: @TaW I thought your suggestion to expand the "stick around" point was worth incorporating, thank you.

Comment: These were just a few things that annoy me on a daily basis. I ask 3 questions and usually not even one gets answered. The first 2-3 hits from feeding the question title into google usually finds a duplicate. Some research effort is required per SO rules. Many posters seem to believe we are more helpful  or even just easier than the debugger or that using it is black magic. And mayn seem to ask in the evening hoping the reap the answers in the morning. - All points potentially help to get good answers and avoid downvotes. The sooner this is pointed out the better for all..

Comment: *"Avoid using the question's tags in the title if you can."* - hmm. Is this really a convention we have? I'd always understood our position to be that tags shouldn't be tacked on to titles (by adding, say, `- Python` or `[JavaScript]` to the end of the title), but that using them naturally as part of the prose of the title (e.g. in a title like "What does Python's `frobnicate()` function do?") was completely fine. As I read your guidance, it seems to be saying that we should try to avoid even the second style of including tags in titles. Why? Is there a reason to do that that I've missed?

Comment: @MarkAmery I was hoping to keep it simple for new users so there is a chance that it gets read. There might be tens of thousands of words written just on just that subject. If a user has to think about the title more, they might even find the solution. I'm sure that after their first few successful questions they will realise when it makes sense to include a tag in the title.